# SQL query "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working on Form that sends about 9 fields to my SQL ACCESS database and i got this error.
"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."
i'm sure it's something with the **'** x **'** i put in my query but still can't figure out what is THE problem.

it's `(int,int,string,string,string,int,int,string,int,int)` format

```
string SqlStr = string.Format("insert into Orders(client_id,order_id,date_,card_typ,pay_mthd,ex_y,ex_m,cc_comp,cc_num,t_sale)values({0},{1},'{2}','{3}','{4}',{5},{6},'{7}',{8},{9})", s.ClientId,s.OrderId,s.Date,s.CardTyp,s.PayMethod,s.Ex_Y,s.Ex_M,s.CcComp,s.CcNum,s.TotalSale);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you share your db structure, and the types of variables you put in?

Comment: Don't use string concatenation (or `String.Format`) to build your sql query. Instead use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection and other (f.e. data type) issues.

Comment: Also, why is `date_` a `varchar` instead of a `date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.Format will not be a good approach for building queries. I suggest you to use, Parameterised queries that helps you to specify the type too and also its more helpful to prevent injection: Here is an example for you:

```
string query = "insert into Orders" +
               "(client_id,order_id,date_,card_typ,...)" +
               " values(@client_id,@order_id,@date_,@card_typ...)";
using (SqlCommand sqCmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    con.Open();
    sqCmd.Parameters.Add("@client_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = s.ClientId;
    sqCmd.Parameters.Add("@order_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = s.OrderId;
    sqCmd.Parameters.Add("@date_", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = s.Date;
    sqCmd.Parameters.Add("@card_typ", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = s.CardTyp;
    // add rest of parameters
   //Execute the commands here
}
```

Note: I have included only few columns in the example, you can replace `...` with rest of columns.

Comment: There is another option just to play around with the **' '** because in other case it worked but i couldn't figure out what was the problem.

this on works: `string SqlStr = string.Format("insert into Orders(client_id,order_id,date_,card_typ,pay_mthd,t_sale)values({0},{1},'{2}','{3}','{4}',{5})",s.ClientId,s.OrderId,s.Date,s.CardTyp,s.PayMethod,s.TotalSale);`

Comment: check the format of the date input, chance for injection

Comment: I know but it's not the issue right now, the issue is that one query works and the other isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont use a concatenation string ...

Here is an example :

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("...connection string ..."))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Orders(client_id,order_id,date_,card_typ,pay_mthd,ex_y,ex_m,cc_comp,cc_num,t_sale)values(@client_id,@order_id,@date_,@card_typ,@pay_mthd,@ex_y,@ex_m,@cc_comp,@cc_num,@t_sale)", connection);
            SqlParameter pclient_id = new SqlParameter("@client_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            pclient_id.Value = 12;
            command.Parameters.Add(pclient_id);
            SqlParameter pcard_typ = new SqlParameter("@card_typ", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
            pcard_typ.Value = "some value";
            command.Parameters.Add(pcard_typ);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Im in senior year in my high-school. I cant do what ever i want because i wont get the maximun point. I just need help to know what's the oroblem behind my query that give me this error. And what is N'' thing?